# Integral equation $u(t)=f(t)+a\int_0^t u(s)ds\quad t\geq 0$

Tags: real-analysis, integration, integral-equations

Let $a\in\mathbb R$ and $f\colon [0,1]\to\mathbb R$ a continuous function. Solve the integral equation
$$u(t)=f(t)+a\int_0^t u(s)\mathrm ds,\quad t\geq 0$$ and find an explicit formula for the solution.       Thank you

Comment: I can't differentiate both sides because f is only continous. I thought of using the contraction theorem

Comment: Do you know what $f$ is? If so, you could try iterating: $$u_{n+1}(t)=f(t)+a\int_{0}^{t}u_{n}(s) \, ds.$$

Comment: I know only that f is a continous function

Comment: Solve first the homogeneous problem ($f=0$) with the iteration and starting with the function $u_0=1$.

Comment: do you mean using differentation: $u'(t)=au(t)\implies u(t)=ce^{at}$ and then?

Comment: See the answer of did.

Comment: Got something from the answer below?

Comment: yes i got it , thank you

Answer (score 4):

One approach is to solve this when $f$ is differentiable, to find a formula for $u$ involving only $f$ (this can be done using integration by parts to get rid of $f'$), and to show that this formula also yields the unique solution when $f'$ does not exist.

Another approach is to consider the function $v=u-f$ and to note that 
$$
v(t)=g(t)+a\int_0^tv(s)\mathrm ds,\qquad g(t)=a\int_0^tf.
$$ 
The function $g$ is $C^1$ hence one can solve this new integral equation the usual way, by differentiatig it. One gets $v'=g'+av$, hence $(\mathrm e^{-at}v(t))'=\mathrm e^{-at}g'(t)$, that is, 
$$
v(t)=\mathrm e^{at}\left(v(0)+\int_0^t\mathrm e^{-as}g'(s)\mathrm ds\right).
$$
Since $v(0)=0$ and $g'=af$, this shows that
$$
u(t)=f(t)+v(t)=f(t)+a\mathrm e^{at}\int_0^t\mathrm e^{-as}f(s)\mathrm ds.
$$
*Sanity check:* The first approach described in this post yields the same formula.